# regex test How to return only exact match

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, testing, exec

I have this code:

```
    var search_term = postAdminID

    // Wildcards Search
    var search = new RegExp(search_term, "i");
    sdsFilter = $.grep(sdsInfo.products, function(element, index) {
        var sted = search.exec(element.AdminID)

        return sted;
```

postAdminID is the index of a spesific post in an array.

element.AdminID is the corresponding index I am seraching for.

PROBLEM:
Whenever I try to execute this search I get every matching index also parts of indexes matched.

Lets say I want to retrieve index #78. The above code returns: 78, 178, 278, 10078 and so forth. I only want the exact index - not every index containing the index.

I have tried .exec and test 
I have looked in every post here on stackoverflow that I can find.

Please help.
How can I specify for regex that it should only look for the entire "string" ?

Comment: What does the string you are trying to match look like?

Comment: I'm assuming you're trying to find one in a list? You would need to add whatever you're using to delimit the items to the search pattern, otherwise it's executing globally because it's treating it as a search [souce: MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec)

Comment: What does search_term include?  Edit your question and include necessary details.  A bit of code does no good without the regex pattern and sample data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is the search pattern you are using.

In REGEX you can match the beginning and the end of the line (of the string in the case of a single-line string). For this, add `^` at the beginning of the search pattern, and `$` at the end.

For example `^78$` will only match the index 78, not 178,278...

If you're looking in a string with delimiters that contains many indexes, you will have to add the delimited in the search pattern, or split the string and search its elementary element.

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex :
`\b78\b`
`\b` will make sure this is only 78, and not a number containing 78.
In your case, search_term should be :
`var search_term = "\b"+postAdminID+"\b"`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your input. Both suggestions did make things work. Except that they restricted use of the script for other purposes. I wanted to use one search algorithm for more than just integer keys.

In the end I ended up with this script, using: **return element.AdminID == postAdminID;**

```
var search_term = postAdminID

// Wildcards Search
var search = new RegExp(search_term, "i");
sdsFilter = $.grep(sdsInfo.products, function(element, index) {
    var sted = search.exec(element.AdminID)
    return element.AdminID == postAdminID;
});
```

I also added several search.exec to the mix in order for my script to become more versatile and flexible. But thank you again for your valuble input.